# WinSCP not running when called from PHP

Tags: php, windows, winscp

I have this line of code:

```
shell_exec("\"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winSCP.exe\" /console /script=c:\\wamp\\www\\client\\transfer_script.txt");
```

The command works in command prompt, and I am sure that it is escaped correctly. Also, I have php safe mode set to off, and no disabled_functions in my php.ini.

I can't get the command to run when I call the php script. Any ideas?

**Edit:**
Now I'm definitely sure it is escaped properly.

Comment: Why are you sure it's escaped properly?  I'd expect to use `\\\` inside the quotes, at least.

Comment: Which space is causing the problem?

Comment: Probably *not* the space actually, I removed that from my comment.

Comment: The reason I am sure about the escaping is that the command runs in cmd, then I just wrapped it in quotes for php and escaped the quotes that were already there. Aside from that I made no other changes so the command should be good.

Comment: But double-quoted strings interpret special sequences in PHP, which you're not escaping. "\t" is a tab, for instance. You'll need to escape your backslashes or use a single-quoted string.

Comment: You should use `winscp.com`, not `winscp.exe`. See http://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's escaped properly.  Consider:

```
// As you have it:
$cmd = "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winSCP.exe\" /console /script=c:\wamp\www\client\transfer_script.txt";
echo $cmd;

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winSCP.exe" /console /script=c:\wamp\www\client ransfer_script.txt
```

That doesn't look right.  Try double-escaping the backslashes outside of the quotes (where pointing to script source):

```
$cmd = "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winSCP.exe\" /console /script=c:\\wamp\\www\\client\\transfer_script.txt";
echo $cmd;

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winSCP.exe" /console /script=c:\wamp\www\client\transfer_script.txt
```

Better.

**UPDATE**

If that still doesn't work I'd try quadruple-escaping with `\\\\`, just in case Windows needs the double-backslashes.  Consider also checking for error codes.

Comment: This is correct. I get the proper command from this, but there is some other problem also, as shell_exec is still not running the command.

Comment: After the call fails, have you checked `print_r(error_get_last())`?